# How to remove part of string value in column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, rename

I have a dataframe:

```
  id                 value
4_french:k_15          10
87_john:k_82           82
11_mark:k_10/k_70      10
1_italian:k_11         9
```

I want to rename values in column id which have `john:k_` giving them new id `john` or `mark` if its `mark:k_` so desired result must be:

```
  id                 value
4_french:k_15          10
john                   82
mark                   10
1_italian:k_11         9
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["id"] = df["id"].str.replace(r'^.*(john|mark):k_.*$', r'\1')
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/R9Jnkh/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

A generic version which assumes that you don't even know what the names might be is:

```py
df["id"] = df["id"].str.replace(r'^.*([a-z]+):k_.*$', r'\1')
```

Comment: the idea was that it can be anything, not only john and mark.

Comment: @french_fries Then replace the alternation `(john|mark)` with whatever the possible values are.  Are you saying there are _more_ known names, or you don't even know what the possible names are?

Comment: I don't even know what the possible names are. it can be anything. so basically I need to cut off undesirable parts from values. I described those undesirable parts